# How to find an alternative international transcript evaluation service?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, international-students, evaluation

I need a career evaluation for applying to a U.S. university graduate program in computer science. I have an official transcript of all my exams in Italian.

I've found this site spantran that evaluates the career, converts the votes to GPA and translates them in English. But it costs 400$, and it asks 65$ for every page translated. I'm here to get to know some cheaper alternative.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "career evaluation". Can you clarify?

Comment: _But it costs 400$_ — **Scam.**  Admissions committees will want the original records in Italian, not the translations.  And your grades/exam scores are not the most important component of your graduate application.

Comment: @JeffE Some universities and employers do, in fact, require that candidates also submit an "evaluation" for foreign transcripts. ([examples](https://www.google.com/#q=%22foreign+transcript+must+be+evaluated%22))

Comment: I need the evaluation to get the GPA average and the translation.

Comment: @ff524 Very few, and almost certainly no strong graduate programs, assuming your results are representative.  In particular, I found [only one (unranked) CS graduate program](http://ww2.tnstate.edu/ece/cisephd.html) that requires a foreign transcript evaluation.

Comment: @JeffE those results are just for one way of phrasing it! Johns Hopkins is one example of a strong university that requires evaluation and/or translation (depending on the program) of international credentials.

Comment: @JeffE from that page: "All application documents must be provided in English (either the original or translations of the original documents) except for samples of work and letters of recommendation for the German and Romance Languages Department. For all other departments and documents, English translation services are available at World Education Services."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The National Association of Credential Evaluation Services is an association of credentials evaluation services in the United States. Of universities that require an evaluation of foreign transcripts, many will also require that this evaluation be done by an NACES member.

The list of NAECS member services is available [**here**](http://www.naces.org/members.html); there are currently 19 services on this list. Now it is up to you to find out which offer the kind of evaluation you need, and what is the cost of each service.

(Note that you need only submit an evaluation if the university you are applying to explicitly requires it; most do not. If they do, they may also require that you use a specific service; check with the university about their requirements.)